# Pyinstaller generated exe doesn't run with Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller, py2exe, windows-task-scheduler

I generated an exe from Pyinstaller, this works perfectly when I double click it but when I try to run it via Task scheduler it never runs but in the history it shows "The operation completed successfully".

To be sure if it ran, I'm logging some text into a log file when the exe runs which never happens via Task scheduler.

Below is the simple snippet of my Python program.

```
import os
import threading
import sys 
import time
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

#Auto-detect zones:
from_zone = tz.tzutc()
to_zone = tz.tzlocal()

logFilespath = 'logs' 
if not os.path.exists(logFilespath):
    os.makedirs(logFilespath)

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create a file handler
todayDate = datetime.now()
todayDate = datetime.strftime(todayDate, '%Y%m%d')  
handler = logging.FileHandler('logs/log' + str(todayDate) + '.log')
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create a logging format
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info('**** Starting KPI Calculations ****')
```

I'm using Python2.7 and tried with py2exe but with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to resolve this:

**1. Find the python executable in your system.**

```
import sys
print("Python EXE: " + sys.executable)
```

In my case: "C:\users\USER\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\python.exe"

**2. Select the path to your python code.**

In my case: "C:\Users\USER\Documents\SandBox\test.py"

**3. Open a notepad and write: 'start PYTHONPATH SCRIPTPATH' as in:**

```
start C:\users\USER\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\USER\Documents\SandBox\test.py
```

**4. Save this notepad as .bat in somewhere.**

**5. Schedule this .bat**

The system will properly run the bat which will run the script.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer how to run the exe created by pyinstaller, just how to run the python code. If this is needed for a computer which doesn't have python (hence the need for the exe), it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I was able to figure out a bit of a work around that gets this working.

I do not understand why trying to run the exe itself doesn't work. I still can't figure that out. So instead, I start an instance of cmd (command prompt) and call the exe from there.

[image: ActionDialog]

When you define the action the task will perform, you need to use the following settings:

Program/script: Point this to the exe for the command prompt. This is usually found in C:\Windows\System32\

Add arguments: type /C and then the exe name (mine was in quotes since the exe name contained spaces, but not sure if that is required). You can put the full path, but I didn't need to because I set the Start In option as well.

Start in: This tells cmd which directory to open in. I pointed this to the directory containing the exe I wanted to run. That way, I didn't have to supply the full path in the Add Arguments field.

So for an example:

Program/script: "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"

Add arguments: /C "myexe.exe"

Start in: "C:\folder1\folder2\folderWithMyExe\"

This worked for me and closed the command prompt after the exe was finished running.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, but finally i fixed it with simple steps.

**Step 1**: Program/script: Put your generate script exe path. here i am using it for attendance. and my pyinstaller generated exe inside *E:\python-scripts\attendance.exe*

**Step 2**: Don't forget to define the folder path in
**Start in**: i.e, *E:\python-scripts*

[Screenshot for Task Schedular Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euc41.png)